# How can I expand containers with jQuery more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to integrate expandable containers in the webpage I'm working on, but I'm having some difficulties with JavaScript code. I'm not able to expand the same container more than once. In ideal case scenario I want to be able to expand/collapse container, and I want only one container to be opened at once. Here is a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ira525axy/8jgopj2a/

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  if ($(".navBoxes").length > 0)
  {
   var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html").item(0);
   var hasCSS3 = (html.className.indexOf("no-csstransforms") == -1)
   
   $(".no-csstransforms .larger").toggleClass("undisplayed");
   $(".larger").children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
   
   // Expand nav box
   $(".nav.plus").click(function(){
            $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
            var smallerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
    var largerBox = smallerBox.next();
    
    if (hasCSS3)
    {
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
     largerBox.toggleClass("atop").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
    }
    else
    {
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
     largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
    }
    
    largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
        largerBox.addClass("openedBox");
        return false;
   });
   
   // Contract nav box
   $(".nav.minus").click(function(){
        var largerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
        $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
    var smallerBox = largerBox.prev();
    
    largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
    
    if (hasCSS3)
    {
     largerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
     largerBox.toggleClass("atop")
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded");
     //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
    }
    else
    {
     largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
    }
    
    return false;
   }); 
  }
  setOrgChartDimensions();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.navBoxes .undisplayed{display: none;}
.navBoxes .navBox{position: absolute; float: left;color: #fff;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller{width: 160px; height: 160px; z-index: 2;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller.atop{z-index: 4;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger{width: inherit; z-index: 1;}
.navBoxes .navBox.hidden{opacity: 0.0;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger.atop{z-index: 3;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .icon{float: left;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller a{color: #fff;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .title{position: relative; top: 10px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body{margin-top: 20px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body a{color: #fff; text-decoration: underline;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav {position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 30px; padding-top: 5px;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav a{color: #fff;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.plus{top: 110px; left: 110px;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.minus{position:relative; float:right;}
.navBoxes .box1 {background-color: #185394; transform-origin: top left;}
.navBoxes .box1.smaller:hover {background-color: #214872;}
.navBoxes .box2 {background-color: #c94747; transform-origin: top right;}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller:hover{background-color: #b24444;}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller{margin-left: 180px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="navBoxes">
 <div class="navBox box1 smaller">
  <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 1</div>
  <div class="nav plus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box1 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
  <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box2 smaller">
  <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 2</a></div>
  <div class="nav plus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box2 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
   <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please simplify the question a bit or put it in a fiddle instead?

Comment: Abhijeet, thank you for your reply. Here is a link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ira525axy/8jgopj2a/

Comment: problem is not removing `undisplayed` second time. Easy to see when inspect the live html in browser dev tools

Comment: thanks for your expertise, can you point at the line that needs to be removed? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first line of your CSS file. Its causing it to always stay hidden.

You are already achieving your goal by manipulating `opacity` and `z-index`. The line to hide it as well is causing it to be forever set to `display: none;`.

If you want to do this with the display method then when "more" is clicked you need to check the current setting of `display` on the element you want to reveal. If it's set to `none` then set it to `block`, and if `block` make it `none`.

Comment: Tyler, thank you for your comment. I don't think this addressing my problem though. Removing line of css will allow end users to expand multiple containers at once, and I don't want that. I want to open only a single container at once.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jgopj2a/5/)

Updated the HTML and JS a bit only.

```
$(function(){
        $('[aria-expanded="false"]').on('click', function(){
            $dt = $(this).parents('.smaller');
            if( $dt.data('target') != undefined ){
                $('.larger.'+$dt.data('target')).toggleClass('hidden').toggleClass('atop');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: This a great, but It looks like I won't be able to close expanded container by clicking on less.

Comment: You can do that as well. Please check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jgopj2a/6/)

Comment: Try to expand first container. Without closing it try to expand the second one. Again, without closing try to expand the first one. It works when you switch between first and second, but if you try to switch again it doesn't work.

Comment: Ohh yeah. In that case, give [it](http://jsfiddle.net/8jgopj2a/7/) a try. Hope, would serve your purpose.